# OpenEMM not starting in Tomcat

Tags: linux, tomcat, ssh, centos

I am trying to install OpenEMM on a Centos6 server. I have Tomcat and Java SDK properly installed and Tomcat runs fine in 8080 when I start it on its own, but when I start OpenEMM it does not open in Tomcat on port 8080 -- I get the error

> Firefox can't establish a connection to the server at
>   www.[myurl].com:8080.

When I start OpenEMM from the ssh command line I get the following. I do not have sendmail worked out so I have disabled it. It appears from the server's response that it's starting.

```
$ bin/openemm.sh start
Start /home/openemm/bin/scripts/bav-update.py .. done.
Start /home/openemm/bin/scripts/bav-trigger.py .. done.
Start /home/openemm/bin/scripts/bavd.py .. done.
Start /home/openemm/bin/bav -L INFO .. done.
Start python /home/openemm/bin/scripts/recovery.py .. done.
Start /home/openemm/bin/scripts/update.py account bounce .. done.
Start /home/openemm/bin/scripts/pickdist.py .. done.
Start /home/openemm/bin/scripts/semu.py .. done.
Start /home/openemm/bin/scripts/slrtscn.py .. done.
Starting up Tomcat ......
Check Java installation          :OK
Check Tomcat installation        :OK
Using CATALINA_BASE:   /home/openemm
Using CATALINA_HOME:   /opt/openemm/tomcat
Using CATALINA_TMPDIR: /home/openemm/temp
Using JRE_HOME:        /opt/openemm/java
Using CLASSPATH:       /opt/openemm/tomcat/bin/bootstrap.jar:/opt/openemm/tomcat/bin/tomcat-juli.jar
```

When I stop OpenEMM I get the following. Interestingly, the stop sequence indicates that Tomcat isn't running. What's happening here?

```
$ bin/openemm.sh stop
No Tomcat is running.
Stop scripts/slrtscn.py program  .. done.
Stop scripts/semu.py program  .. done.
Stop scripts/pickdist program  .. done.
Stop scripts/update.py program  .. done.
Stop bin/bav program with signal 15 .. done.
Stop bin/bav program with signal 9 .. done.
Stop scripts/bavd program  .. done.
Stop scripts/bav-trigger program with signal 15 .. done.
Stop scripts/bav-update program with signal 15 .. done.
```

Here are my logs from the /home/openemm/tomcat/logs folder:

From catalina.2013-10-12.log:

```
Oct 12, 2013 9:00:22 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
WARNING: Catalina.start using conf/server.xml: Error at (24, 78) : org.apache.catalina.mbeans.ServerLifecycleListener
Oct 12, 2013 9:00:22 AM org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.Digester startElement
SEVERE: Begin event threw exception
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.catalina.mbeans.ServerLifecycleListener
     at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
     at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
     at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
     at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
     at org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.ObjectCreateRule.begin(ObjectCreateRule.java:116)
     at org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.Digester.startElement(Digester.java:1176)
     at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.startElement(AbstractSAXParser.java:506)
     at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractXMLDocumentParser.emptyElement(AbstractXMLDocumentParser.java:182)
     at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanStartElement(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:1347)
     at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDriver.next(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:2768)
     at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:606)
     at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:511)
     at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:846)
     at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:775)
     at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(XMLParser.java:123)
     at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(AbstractSAXParser.java:1210)
     at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(SAXParserImpl.java:628)
     at org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.Digester.parse(Digester.java:1449)
     at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load(Catalina.java:582)
     at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:646)
     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
     at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
     at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:357)
     at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:491)
Oct 12, 2013 9:00:22 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
WARNING: Catalina.start using conf/server.xml: Error at (24, 78) : org.apache.catalina.mbeans.ServerLifecycleListener
Oct 12, 2013 9:00:22 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
SEVERE: Cannot start server. Server instance is not configured.
```

Comment: What is in the Tomcat log files?

Comment: I added the logs above -- too long for the comment box.

Comment: Tomcat version (all three digits please)?

Comment: apache-tomcat-8.0.0-CR1

Comment: Note that OpenEMM recommends to use Tomcat 6, higher version are not (yet) supported. I installed everything in a Centos 6 and it works well (but I had to choose OpenEMM 2013 R2, not the OpenEMM 2013)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you mean Apache Tomcat 8.0.0-RC1. Note RC3 is available and RC4 should be out next week (assuming I can track down and fix the one remaining issue quickly).

The problem is that you are using a server.xml file from Tomcat 6.0.x (or possibly earlier) and it contains references to components that have been removed in later versions. You'd be better off starting with a clean server.xml from Tomcat 8 and adding what you need.

The other option is to fix each error one at a time until Tomcat starts. The fix for the first error is to removed the ServerLifecycleListener entirely.

Comment: So, Tomcat 8 RC1 didn't have the correct server.xml in the package? Should I be upgrading to RC3? I was thinking this might be the problem and was going to remove the Tomcat installation and revert to an older version but I was unable to get it to uninstall with yum. Is there an update command I can run to update Tomcat?

Comment: I've downloaded the tarball for RC3 but RC1 won't uninstall. This is what I get:
yum remove apache-tomcat-8.0.0-RC1
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, priorities
Setting up Remove Process
No Match for argument: apache-tomcat-8.0.0-RC1
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
* base: p3plmirror01.prod.phx3.secureserver.net
* extras: p3plmirror01.prod.phx3.secureserver.net
* updates: p3plmirror01.prod.phx3.secureserver.net
base | 3.7 kB     00:00
extras | 3.4 kB     00:00
updates | 3.4 kB     00:00
No Packages marked for removal

Comment: Slowly progressing -- thanks, you've put me on the right track. I deleted the apache-tomcat-8.0.0-RC1 directory and installed RC3, then replaced the service.xml and web.xml files in /home/openemm/conf/. Now I've got another issue, but Tomcat is trying to load and after working through the logs I'm getting what looks like a clean start. Still getting a blank page at localhost:8080, though. Good grief.